# Sum matrices without using Loops

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, matrix, addition

I have a project where many matrices will need to be summed together. Currently, this is accomplished through a while loop for each iteration. Is there a faster way to sum matrices using maybe built in programming?

From my research so far, all matrix summation done through VBA is through looping, which I believe won't improve the run speed.

Comment: You can unroll loops, but if you're concerned about performance, why not use a .Net matrix library that's performant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Evaluate` to sum matrices as ranges. For instance:

```
Dim ar
ar = Sheet1.Evaluate("A1:C3 + E1:G3 + I1:K3")
```

returns an array (matrix) that is the sum of the 3 matrices.

However if you mean to sum VBA arrays element by element and return a result array, then loop is the only option.

Comment: I see, thank you for the reply! I might have to export the data to a third party program for evaluation and then return the results back into excel.

Comment: @TJYen I guess your goal is to exploit multi-processing capabilities. In that case, indeed the VBA loop wont do it (The Exce/Evaluate version will probably do it, not sure though, needs some testing).